# Athena Query called by AWS Lambda function not returning results

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to use this AWS Lambda to get results from an Amazon Athena query.

This is the Lambda function:

```py
import boto3

# Query string to execute
query = 'SELECT DISTINCT awsaccountid, digeststarttime FROM smxtech.cloudtrail_digest'

# Database to execute the query against
DATABASE = 'xtech'

# Output location for query results
output='s3://xtech-destination/'

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # Initiate the Boto3 Client
    client = boto3.client('athena')

    # Start the query execution
    response = client.start_query_execution(
        QueryString=query,
        QueryExecutionContext={
            'Database': DATABASE
        },
        ResultConfiguration={
            'OutputLocation': output
        }
    )

    # Return response after starting the query execution
    return response
```

I get an error:

```json
{
  "QueryExecutionId": "6e9fa646-d8e2-4d11-b61f-579091f1a714",
  "ResponseMetadata": {
    "RequestId": "704e1467-3c8a-46c6-8cfa-04b8bf34bc6c",
    "HTTPStatusCode": 200,
    "HTTPHeaders": {
      "date": "Sun, 05 Feb 2023 02:13:18 GMT",
      "content-type": "application/x-amz-json-1.1",
      "content-length": "59",
      "connection": "keep-alive",
      "x-amzn-requestid": "704e1467-3c8a-46c6-8cfa-04b8bf34bc6c"
    },
    "RetryAttempts": 0
  }
}
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this error?

Answer (score 1):

That is not an error. Your code is working perfectly.

The `start_query_execution()` API call *starts* execution of a query.

You can *monitor* the status of the query with `get_query_execution()`, which also returns the status of the query (`'QUEUED'|'RUNNING'|'SUCCEEDED'|'FAILED'|'CANCELLED'`).

When the query has succeeded, you can retrieve the results with [`get_query_results()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/athena.html#Athena.Client.get_query_results).

Comment: I figured it out after posting this. Thanks.